# Send JSON Post Request to Contact Form 7

Tags: android, ios, json, react-native, contact-form-7

I am developing mobile application with React Native for both IOS/Android. Mobile application is for a website that built with Wordpress. In contact page they are using Contact Form 7, and I want to send Post request to that page to send email. I wonder how to do that? I took a look to /wp-json but couldn't figure it out. Any Ideas?

Comment: your mobile app is a WebView displaying the website? if yes, why do i need to call the POST API!

Comment: No, it is not WebView. I could do that but my navbar is differenent from the one in website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this wordpress plugin to create API for Contact from 7 https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-to-api/ (sunsetted on  January 30, 2019)

on the reactNative call the POST API: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html